# YouTube playlist differs when viewed from MacOS vs. Windows

Tags: macos, youtube, windows-10, playlist

I am developing a YouTube channel (not published yet).  My prototype Playlist has 4 videos as I last edited the Playlist, and when viewed from other Macs, all 4 play in sequence.

But, when I access the channel through a browser on Win10, the 2nd video is missing from the playlist.  Confirmed with Edge and Firefox Win10 browsers.

The only thing different about the 2nd video is that, I needed to make mods to it.  I had to delete the original, post the replacement vid, then resequence the Playlist to put it where it belongs (2nd place in the Playlist).

Any idea why the Playlist comes out missing the newest video when viewed from Windows10?

Here is the private link to the Playlist:  https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLgQb6MPMYTjyV82sR8H9hXRQ2F5s2NFsP

Comment: One clue...the 3 videos that show on all computers tested were posted 1 year ago.  The video that is missing on some computers was posted a week ago.

Comment: I just tested the playlist on an iPad Pro with Safari, and the 2nd vid is missing from the playlist there, too.   Very weird.

Answer (score 0):

For private videos and playlists, the viewer must:

1. have a YouTube account and be signed in
2. have received an invitation from the channel creator

These steps were omitted in testing the channel on various of my own computers, and on friends' computers.

This is the most likely explanation.  Will report back.

Answer (score 0):

This was simply a problem where the odd video was posted with different visibility (Private) than the other 3 (Unlisted).

If you're not working in a high-security environment, Unlisted is much more practical for testing and reviewing pre-pub YouTubes.  The browser only needs a URL pointing to the video (or playlist).

Private is for high-security projects where you cannot trust the testers to keep the links you give them private.